# Derivative of the summation of the log

Tags: calculus, derivatives, summation, logarithms

Given the function $f(t) = \sum^n_{i=1}{log[(x_i)^{t-1}]}$ where x > 0.

What is the derivative of $f(t)$ with respect to t?

Comment: Apply the property $\log{x_i^t}=t\log{x_i}$ then differentiate the summation by summing the individual derivatives to get the sum of the logs. I'm on my phone right now, so sorry if I'm not that clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$f(t) = \sum^n_{i=1}{log[(x_i)^{t-1}]}$$

$$=(t-1)\sum^n_{i=1}{log(x_i)}$$

$$ f'(t) = \sum^n_{i=1}{log(x_i)}$$

Comment: What happens to the (t-1) on the final step?

Comment: We are taking derivative with respect to $t$. Thus its derivative is $1$ and the rest is a constant multiple , so the $t-1$ disappears.

Answer (score 1):

Hint :

Use the fact that :

$$\ln[x^t]=t\ln x$$